# Arquillian: Transaction is required to perform this operation

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly, jta, jboss-arquillian

I´m trying to run our JPA Unit tests with arquillian- with an embedded wildfly.
So far, i got the following steps working when i do a clean&build on project:

1. embedded wildfly will get deployed in the /target folder of project
2. MSSQL-database driver will be deployed and registered as driver
3. arquillian creates a .war file with all required dependencies
4. arquillian deploys the .war of my project to the embedded wildfly and starts the unit test on the embedded wildfly

**Now my problem:** I´m getting the following exception, when i call a .create() or .delete() method on entitymanager inside my unit tests:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

These are the important dependencies of my pom.xml:

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-test-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>



</dependencies>
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-db-driver</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>datasource</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=tests</address>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <properties>
                                        <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERADRESS_CENSORED;instanceName=web;databaseName=TMCDB</connection-url>
                                        <jndi-name>java:jdbc/TMCDB</jndi-name>
                                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        <enable>true</enable>
                                        <user-name>USER_CENSORED</user-name>
                                        <password>PW_CENSORED</password>
                                        <driver-name>sqljdbc-4.0.2206.100.jar</driver-name>
                                        <use-ccm>false</use-ccm>
                                    </properties>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Inside my persistence.xml, i´ve set the transaction-type="JTA".

And here´s the part, where the .war file gets created by arquillian/shrinkwrap.
This stuff is annotated with the @Deployment tag of Arquillian:

```
PomEquippedResolveStage loadPomFromFile = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
        File[] asFile = loadPomFromFile.importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();


        //MavenStrategyStage asFile = loadPomFromFile.importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve();

        WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addAsLibraries(asFile)
                .addPackages(true, "de.companyXYZ")
                .addPackages(true, "org.springframework.beans.factory.config")
                // Adding persistence unit
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                // Add ms-sql driver for the embedded wildfly
                .addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds-driver.xml")
                // Add datasource for the embedded wildfly
                .addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        webArchive.as(ZipExporter.class).exportTo(new File("./target/test-package.war"), true);
```

So, can anybody help me with this problem? 
I don´t understand why i´m getting this Exception- cause the wildfly should do the transaction management- that´s what i expect of him...

Comment: could you please tell how you have acquired entityManager?

Comment: I´m getting the entityManager with dependency injection- the container shall give me an instance of it:

 @Inject
 @PersistenceType(PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
 private EntityManager em;

So in the code, i´m just calling something like em.create(projectEntity);
And the embedded wildfly shall give me with dependency injection an instance of the entitymanager...

Comment: Please add some test code to your question so we can see what your test is doing in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I add, and that solves my issues with transactions

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.api.annotation.Transactional;

    @Transactional
```

Comment: Where did you add this? On the method, where you call the .create() ? Or to the entity classes?

Comment: right ontop of the testmethod, just like a regular transaction annotates on regular methods.